# String filtering for movie names in java

Tags: java, string

I have to get the list of all movie names from a directory but I only want the filtered names only not the
extra information generally attached to a movie name.

For ex. in (Wall-E [DVDrip] [Dual Audio] [Eng-Hindi]-$am3e) this string i only want the string (Wall -E) to be returned I want to filter all the similar irrelevant information from the movie name strings.

Can any one suggest me how I may achieve this in JAVA.
Only approach I can think of is brute-force replacement of all unnecessary strings
code snippet is:

```
    for(String list1 : list) {
          if(list1.contains("DvDrip[Eng]-FXG"))
               list1.replaceAll("DvDrip[Eng]-FXG","");

          else if(list1.contains("Blu-Ray x264 [Dual-Audio][Hindi-English]"))
               list1.replaceAll("Blu-Ray x264 [Dual-Audio][Hindi-English]","");

          else if(list1.cotains("10n80p.BRRip.x264.AAC-ETRG"))
               list1.replaceAll("1080p.BRRip.x264.AAC-ETRG","");
}
```

Can anyone tell me a better approach?

Comment: a) maybe you should use `replace` as `replaceAll` accepts regex as its input `[Eng]` would confuse it.  b) Strings are immutable and the `replace` method retuns the changed String.

Comment: c) checking the contains condition is pointless. just replace. d) you'll have more success replacing small strings, like "[Eng]" e) consider using a regex to get rid of all the "[...]" items. then state as such in your question

Comment: Is the movie name contains space? If not I will suggest splitting the string by space and using the first string in the resulted staring array.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing this would be to maintain a collection of all targets to replaced/removed, and then use `String#replaceAll` with an alternation:

```
List<String> targets = Arrays.asList("DvDrip[Eng]-FXG", "Blu-Ray x264 [Dual-Audio][Hindi-English]", "10n80p.BRRip.x264.AAC-ETRG");
targets = targets.stream().map(x -> Pattern.quote(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
String regex = "(?<!\\S)(?:" + String.join("|", targets) + ")(?!\\S)";
String input = "DvDrip[Eng]-FXG Hello World Blu-Ray x264 [Dual-Audio][Hindi-English] Goodbye";
System.out.println(input);
input = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(input);
```

This prints:

```
DvDrip[Eng]-FXG Hello World Blu-Ray x264 [Dual-Audio][Hindi-English] Goodbye
 Hello World  Goodbye
```

At first sight, the above code snippet appears perhaps more verbose than what you have now.  But keep in mind that it would work for any number of replacements, while your current approach would just keep requiring more code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each list element uses the same pattern, i.e. starts with an opening parenthesis `(` and after the movie name there is a single space followed by character `[`, then I suggest using the following code which utilizes java regular expressions.

```java
Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile("^\\((\\S+.*?) \\["); 
Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher("(Wall-E [DVDrip] [Dual Audio] [Eng-Hindi]-$am3e)");
if (mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group(1));
}
```

Note that the above code uses the sample input that you posted in your question.
The `String` returned by `mtchr.group(1)` is

> Wall-E